# How to display .txt file in a TextView from ListView onClickItem?

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I am working on the below but I am finding troubles in reading a .txt file from a `ListView`, displaying it in a `TextView`.

The code is:

```
    ArrayList<String> AcqList = GetFiles("/sdcard/Muse");

    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AcqList));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View vr, int position, long id) {
    **????**
    }
    private boolean checkResults(String fileName){

    File file = new File("/sdcard/MuSe/"+fileName);

    if(file.exists()) return true;

    else return false;
}

});
return vr;
}
```

I need to complete the `???` part with the code who reads the file .txt and display it in the `TextView` with id AcqText. In the `ListView` I show a list of .txt file in a specific directory.

Comment: To be clear, I am in a fragment and below that code, i have the ArrayList showing the .txt file list.

Answer (score 0):

You should store those files in assets or raw directory and after that you can get inputstream from those files by using ,

If using **assets**

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("yourfilename.txt");
```

**OR** if you use raw directory then ,

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfilename);
```

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to open one specific file "myfilename.txt" but i want to open the file on which i click on my app. Is this the same process that you invite me to do?

Comment: You can use that code snippet in the list item click listener. Firstly you have to get the item id and if matches the required value then show the .txtfile accordingly. Did you get my point?

Comment: Nope sorry, didn't get it. Can u codify it please?